# EventListener not registering upon using replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, replacewith

First I am cloning yesDelete button and storing it in "replace". Then I am replacing yesDelete with replace. after that, when I am trying to register an EventListener to yesDelete, it is not getting registered. Could someone please help? Thanks

```
 let yesDelete = deleteModal.querySelector(".btn--danger")
 const startDeletingMovieHandler = (movieId) =>{

    let replace = yesDelete.cloneNode(true)
    yesDelete.replaceWith(replace)
    yesDelete.addEventListener("click", yesDeleteHandler.bind(null,movieId))
    confirmDelete()

}
```

Comment: olease read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  there is nothing understandable and reproducible in your question

Comment: I believe the issue is you are not replacing the var `yesDelete` with `replace` you are replacing in the DOM where `yesDelete` was. so the var `yesDelete` has not changed.
if you call `addEventListener` on `replace` it would work